# Eclipse plugin develop PDE: Could not create the view: org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesView

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, egit

I am developing my own Eclipse plugin with Eclipse RCP 2020-09. I am adding egit bundles in Perspective via Model Fragments. I do the following steps:

1. Create a Part - Git Repositories in a Model Fragment for TrimmedWindow - sharedElements
2. Add bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView in Part Class URI and name the Part ID org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesView
3. Add the created Part in the Perspective Placeholder.

Here is the XMI format for my fragment.e4xmi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<fragment:ModelFragments xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:advanced="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/advanced" xmlns:basic="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/descriptor/basic" xmlns:basic_1="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/basic" xmlns:commands="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/commands" xmlns:fragment="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/fragment" xmlns:menu="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui/menu" xmlns:ui="http://www.eclipse.org/ui/2010/UIModel/application/ui" xmi:id="_BxaXACerEeWxCPrV0pAZQQ">
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_TKjkcA4zEeuv3ZS4n7QGUw" featurename="descriptors" parentElementId="xpath:/">
    <elements xsi:type="basic:PartDescriptor" xmi:id="_dSdBgA4zEeuv3ZS4n7QGUw" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.partdescriptor.cattodev" label="Catto" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/Sample.png" category="CattoDev" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/catto.plugin.adapter.views.SampleView">
      <tags>View</tags>
      <tags>categoryTag:CattoDev</tags>
    </elements>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_QqSikIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" featurename="commands" parentElementId="xpath:/">
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Command" xmi:id="_UCYfwIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="test.handler.helloWorldCommand" commandName="Hello World"/>
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Command" xmi:id="_TxosMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.command.goodbyeworld" commandName="Goodbye World"/>
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Command" xmi:id="_Ya-xIBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.command.tabby" commandName="Tabby"/>
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Command" xmi:id="_aGnMgBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.command.shibo" commandName="Shibo"/>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_fW12kIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" featurename="handlers" parentElementId="xpath:/">
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Handler" xmi:id="_k2L0IIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.handler.0" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/com.catto.ide.dev.handlers.HelloWorldHandler" command="_UCYfwIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw"/>
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Handler" xmi:id="_WggGMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handler.0" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/com.catto.ide.dev.handlers.GoodByeWorldHandler" command="_TxosMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA"/>
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Handler" xmi:id="_b64mgBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handler.1" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/com.catto.ide.dev.handlers.TabbyHandler" command="_Ya-xIBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ"/>
    <elements xsi:type="commands:Handler" xmi:id="_ealjIBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handler.2" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/com.catto.ide.dev.handlers.ShiboHandler" command="_aGnMgBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ"/>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_pVgfIIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" featurename="menuContributions" parentElementId="xpath:/">
    <elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_tSwX0IrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.menucontribution.0" positionInParent="after=additions" parentId="org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
      <children xsi:type="menu:Menu" xmi:id="_wg9ZMIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.menu.e4handlers" label="Catto">
        <visibleWhen xsi:type="ui:ImperativeExpression" xmi:id="_kgDgEBlJEeuO-abULpdSNA" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/com.catto.ide.dev.handlers.MenuContributionsHandler"/>
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_2LM_MIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.handledmenuitem." label="" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/Sample.png" command="_UCYfwIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw"/>
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_fD1ZMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handledmenuitem.0" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/filter_internal_targets.png" command="_TxosMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA"/>
      </children>
    </elements>
    <elements xsi:type="menu:MenuContribution" xmi:id="_BducUIrPEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.menucontribution.1" positionInParent="after=additions" parentId="popup">
      <children xsi:type="menu:Menu" xmi:id="_Dtii0IrPEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.menu.e4handlers" label="E4 Handlers" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/Sample.png">
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_Dtii0YrPEeW7h_qdP9N9fw" elementId="org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.handledmenuitem." label="" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/Sample.png" command="_UCYfwIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw"/>
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_zayEMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handledmenuitem.1" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/filter_internal_targets.png" command="_TxosMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA"/>
      </children>
    </elements>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_cIcUMA4tEeufe5zGX17fuA" featurename="trimContributions" parentElementId="xpath:/">
    <elements xsi:type="menu:TrimContribution" xmi:id="_fGn8kA4tEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.trimcontribution.CattoDev" accessibilityPhrase="" parentId="org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar" positionInParent="">
      <children xsi:type="menu:ToolBar" xmi:id="_lSmWoA4tEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.toolbar.CattoDev" accessibilityPhrase="">
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_mbsFoA4tEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handledtoolitem.0" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/Sample.png" command="_UCYfwIrOEeW7h_qdP9N9fw"/>
        <children xsi:type="menu:HandledToolItem" xmi:id="_DBclIA4uEeufe5zGX17fuA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handledtoolitem.1" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/filter_internal_targets.png" command="_TxosMA4rEeufe5zGX17fuA"/>
      </children>
    </elements>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_sz25QBNqEeubfohgYRL3mA" featurename="snippets" parentElementId="xpath:/">
    <elements xsi:type="advanced:Perspective" xmi:id="_vyUOcBNqEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.perspective.snowcatto" accessibilityPhrase="" label="SnowCatto">
      <children xsi:type="basic_1:PartSashContainer" xmi:id="_E_gEQBNzEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.partsashcontainer.0">
        <children xsi:type="basic_1:PartSashContainer" xmi:id="_LQkZsBNzEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="top" containerData="75" horizontal="true">
          <children xsi:type="basic_1:PartStack" xmi:id="_5AmM0BNzEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.partstack.0" containerData="26">
            <children xsi:type="advanced:Placeholder" xmi:id="_PP0rQBN4EeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer" ref="_Ww7GMBkDEea2ENFkqfwc7g"/>
            <children xsi:type="advanced:Placeholder" xmi:id="_RwEzwBNzEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesView" ref="_cVUtcBkEEea2ENFkqfwc7g"/>
          </children>
          <children xsi:type="advanced:Placeholder" xmi:id="_cQ_00BNzEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.editorss" containerData="74" ref="_dweAUBNvEeubfohgYRL3mA"/>
        </children>
        <children xsi:type="basic_1:PartSashContainer" xmi:id="_qXvGABNzEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="bottom" containerData="25" horizontal="true">
          <children xsi:type="basic_1:PartStack" xmi:id="_mYNFoBOEEeuok7ixJwbT8A" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.partstack.1">
            <children xsi:type="advanced:Placeholder" xmi:id="_J0-poBkCEea2ENFkqfwc7g" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" containerData="74" ref="_DHSpoBkCEea2ENFkqfwc7g"/>
            <children xsi:type="advanced:Placeholder" xmi:id="_qCy5MBUSEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="gunnars.ide.part.toolbelt" ref="_yWl3IBkCEea2ENFkqfwc7g"/>
            <children xsi:type="basic_1:Part" xmi:id="_l4T1wBUSEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.part.psipsi" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/catto.plugin.perspective.parts.PerspectivePart" label="Psi Psi" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/ancestorpane_co.png">
              <menus xmi:id="_eA9lYBUaEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.menu.0" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/eclipse16.png">
                <tags>ViewMenu</tags>
                <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_eY8AgBUaEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handledmenuitem.tabby" label="Tabby" command="_Ya-xIBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ"/>
                <children xsi:type="menu:HandledMenuItem" xmi:id="_ezyJcBUaEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ" elementId="com.catto.ide.dev.handledmenuitem.shibo" label="Shibo" command="_aGnMgBUWEeu_Lpb-A4VglQ"/>
              </menus>
            </children>
          </children>
        </children>
      </children>
    </elements>
  </fragments>
  <fragments xsi:type="fragment:StringModelFragment" xmi:id="_R0MbkBNvEeubfohgYRL3mA" featurename="sharedElements" parentElementId="IDEWindow">
    <elements xsi:type="advanced:Area" xmi:id="_dweAUBNvEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.editorss" label="Editor Area">
      <children xsi:type="basic_1:PartStack" xmi:id="_hq_8MBNvEeubfohgYRL3mA" elementId="org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack">
        <tags>org.eclipse.e4.primaryDataStack</tags>
        <tags>EditorStack</tags>
      </children>
    </elements>
    <elements xsi:type="basic_1:Part" xmi:id="_DHSpoBkCEea2ENFkqfwc7g" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView" label="Console" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.console/icons/full/cview16/console_view.png"/>
    <elements xsi:type="basic_1:Part" xmi:id="_yWl3IBkCEea2ENFkqfwc7g" elementId="gunnars.ide.part.toolbelt" contributionURI="bundleclass://com.catto.ide.dev/catto.plugin.perspective.parts.CatCommand" label="Toolbelt Commands" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/template_obj.png"/>
    <elements xsi:type="basic_1:Part" xmi:id="_Ww7GMBkDEea2ENFkqfwc7g" elementId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView" label="Project Explorer" iconURI="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.ide.application/icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.png"/>
    <elements xsi:type="basic_1:Part" xmi:id="_cVUtcBkEEea2ENFkqfwc7g" elementId="org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesView" contributionURI="bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView" label="Git Repositories" iconURI="platform:/plugin/com.catto.ide.dev/icons/org.png"/>
  </fragments>
</fragment:ModelFragments>
```

When I run the software, the Git Reposiroties tab appears but there is an error saying: **Could not create the view: org.eclipse.egit.ui.RepositoriesView**. I checked several posts and most of them said that updating the software will solve everything, but my software is the latest. My egit version is 5.9.0. I think this happens to me because of I do something wrong in my code. Can you give me any ideas or advices? Here is the log file:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createErrorPart(ViewReference.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:338)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:730)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.lambda$0(PartServiceImpl.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4725)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.lambda$4(StackRenderer.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1879)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.lambda$0(CTabFolder.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4012)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3612)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Thanks and best regards,
Duy

Comment: I don't think compatability mode views are defined like that (see for example [this discussion](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/358552/) but personally I have never done this so I am not sure what the correct method is,

Comment: Hi @greg-449, actually I followed the examples in [the discussion](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/358552/) you mentioned and the egit integration has this problem. Console View, Editor... have no problem.